# Not able to search for misspelled words in Oracle Column

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a query in Oracle where the searched column in a table could contain a word, or in my example, an email has been entered incorrectly.

Using ORACLE TEXT I have created a query that does some of what I want -

```
select score(1), string
from   TEST
where  contains(string,'fuzzy(joe@email.com,1, 2)',1) > 0;
```

But in the example about if a user in an application has entered in email as `jeo@mail.com` or `jeo@email.com`, is there a way in the query to return rows that are "near" to the search?

Comment: If you're looking for similar column values, `UTL_MATCH` has 2 edit distance options.

Answer (score 2):

As kfinity suggested, `UTL_MATCH` might help. Here's an example, see whether you can use it.

```
SQL> with test (id, col1, col2) as
  2    (select 1, 'joe@mail.com'   , 'joe@email.com'  from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'jeo@email.com'  , 'john@email.com' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'lf@gmail.com'   , 'joe@email.com'  from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'andy@mail.com'  , 'andy@mail.com'  from dual
  6    )
  7  select id, col1, col2,
  8    utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(col1, col2) sim
  9  from test
 10  order by id;

        ID COL1          COL2                  SIM
---------- ------------- -------------- ----------
         1 joe@mail.com  joe@email.com          98
         2 jeo@email.com john@email.com         90
         3 lf@gmail.com  joe@email.com          81
         4 andy@mail.com andy@mail.com         100

SQL>
```

The last column represents *how much* those values match. 100 means that they are matched. Now, if you wanted to extract pairs that differ *too much*, you can use it as a subquery and then

```
  <snip>
  7  select id, col1, col2, sim
  8  from (select id, col1, col2,
  9          utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(col1, col2) sim
 10        from test
 11       )
 12  where sim < 90
 13  order by id;

        ID COL1          COL2                  SIM
---------- ------------- -------------- ----------
         3 lf@gmail.com  joe@email.com          81

SQL>
```